# Flutter web app on Windows -how to support mouse drag for horizontal and vertical scrolling as well as using mouse wheel

Tags: flutter

With a Flutter web app running on Windows 10, the default option for enacting scrolling is via the mouse wheel.

Is it possible to set up additional options for scrolling, like a mouse drag down action for vertical scrolling, or mouse drag across action for horizontal scrolling?